# C# BindingSource Combobox данные из другой таблицы

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, bindingsource

В С# + MS SQL через ADO.NET есть так скажем 2 таблицы:

1. Контакты, в который указан вторичный ключ по полю IDGroup таблицы Группы.
2. Группы.

На изображение видно, что на combobox в форме контактов идет биндинг из таблицы группы, чтобы нам показывало (в комбобоксе) название группы, а в запись шел ее код.
Проблема в том, что биндинг вроде бы и указан, но при работе программы комбобокс пуст. В нем нет ничего, информация из таблицы группы не отображается.
Хотелось бы узнать почему и возможно ли это исправить.
[image: При работе]
[image: Биндинг]

Comment: В БД данные то есть в той таблице? Источник данных какой запрос посылает?

Comment: Да, данные есть. А вот про запрос не совсем все понял.

Comment: + если через DataSet добавить, то все отображается. Но хотелось бы узнать, почему просто через биндинг пусто и возможно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы все таки данные показывались/передавались.

Comment: Ваша программа общается с SQL сервером через SQL звпросы. Вы либо смотрите, как ваш источник данных сконфигурирован и понимаете, какой он запрос посылает. Либо запускаете SQL Profiler и смотрите все запросы к БД и ищете среди них запрос от вашего источника данных. Когда увидите запрос, поймете а чем проблема.

Comment: @tym32167 Не уверен, что я все правильно понял, но если вместо комбобокса вставить текстбокс и забиндить его на IDGroup из таблицы контакты, то все работает и добавляется/меняется/удаляется. Сейчас проверил запрос, которые происходит при запуске формы, то там все правильно, вроде как.

Comment: @tym32167 SELECT 
    [Extent1].[IDHuman] AS [IDHuman], 
    [Extent1].[FIO] AS [FIO], 
    [Extent1].[IDGroup] AS [IDGroup], 
    [Extent1].[Address] AS [Address], 
    [Extent1].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [Extent1].[Birthday] AS [Birthday], 
    [Extent1].[Note] AS [Note]
    FROM [dbo].[Contacts] AS [Extent1]

Comment: покажите настройки вашего источника данных